Unquote JSON data in CLI
I have a script, that returns quoted JSON data, like "{\"F1\":null,\"F2\":\"text\"...
How can I evaluate it and return "clear" data to feed it into jq?

Please share more details (see: https://www.google.com/search?q=unquote+JSON+data+site%3Astackoverflow.com, for a list of current possible duplicate questions......)

It's a JSON value, encode as a JSON string. Decode it once, you get the JSON object; decode that, and you get the dict/hash/etc that the programming language of your choice interprets a JSON object as.

"{\"F1\":null,\"F2\":\"text\"}" is in fact a valid JSON value. It's a JSON string that happens to contain valid JSON encoded as a string.
You can either use fromjson as the initial filter in your jq program or use jq once to print the raw string contents:
echo '"{\"F1\":null,\"F2\":\"text\"}"' | jq 'fromjson | ...'

or
echo '"{\"F1\":null,\"F2\":\"text\"}"' | jq -r . | jq '...'

